# Jenkins - Get last completed build status

Tags: jenkins

I know I can call `localhost/job/RSpec/lastBuild/api/json` to get the status of the lastest Jenkins build. However, since our build runs very long (a couple hours), I'm really more interested in the last **complete** build status than the run that is *running at this exact moment*.

Is there an API end point for the last fully run build? Or should I instead pull the full list of builds and select the next-to-last one from there?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Try http://$host/job/$jobname/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/json

Jenkins (and Hudson) expose multiple different builds, such as [lastBuild, lastStableBuild, lastSuccessfulBuild, lastFailedBuild, lastUnstableBuild, lastUnsuccessfulBuild, lastCompletedBuild](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Terminology).

Comment: Wondering if there is a way to do this for all the jobs in a view.

Comment: Yep @SteventheEasilyAmused, just do .../job/$jobname/api/json?depth=2

Comment: NOTE: at least as of Jenkins 2.263.3, if there has never been a successful build for $jobname, this API endpoint will return an HTML 404 Error page

Answer (score 11):

To get the last successful build number:

```
curl --user <userName:password> https://<url>/job/<job-Name>/api/xml?xpath=/*/lastSuccessfulBuild/number
```

Answer (score 1):

JenkinsAPI is also a nice option. I'm mainly using python and so here is my version of things:

1. `pip install jenkinsapi`
2. python code: (in my case no special authentication to Jenkins is needed, otherwise i assume a token is needed)

```py
from jenkinsapi.jenkins import Jenkins
server = Jenkins(<Jenkins server URL>)
job = server.get_job(<job name>)
last_successful_build_number = job.get_last_good_buildnumber()
```