# Jenkins get last but one build status

Tags: json, jenkins

I can get the last build (successful/failed) from the json api of jenkins like mentioned in the below stack overflow link,

[Jenkins - Get last completed build status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238616/jenkins-get-last-completed-build-status)

My question is, how can I get the last but one build status?? Please let me know if there is a way to achieve this.

My ultimate aim is to get the build status of the previous build status in a loop until a particular date is reached.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to use the API results paging mechanism (introduced in Jenkins 1.568).

Builds are listed in reverse chronological order, so you can start at offset `1` (instead of the default of `0`) to get the second item in the list — the last-but-one.

To get the build status, check the `result` field, for example:
`$JENKINS_URL/job/$JOB/api/json?tree=builds[number,result]{1,2}`

This returns a list of builds between offset `1` and `2`, i.e. one build in total.

Answer (score 1):

You know you current build number, during the job. It's `$BUILD_NUMBER`. Also found under `"number":` if using `/lastBuild/api/json`.

Subtract 1 from that, and that's your previous build (unless plugins mess with build number sequentiality). So now use `/build_number/api/json`, just replace the `build_number` with the one you calculated

Comment: how to get last second build?