# Direct url to the lastest details page of a build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I try to set up a public display on our department floor to present the current status of the Jenkin's maintained projects. Therefore I'm cycling through a session of Jenkins web pages like the Blue Ocean Pipeline overview or the detailed build history of particular pipelines.
[Blue Ocean Pipeline Build History](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAT4u.png)

Additionally I would like to show the detailed page of the last build step of a pipeline.
[Build details of a pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIp1Q.png)

Unfortunately the url that is been called uses the build number which I don't have on my script side. Is there a way within Blue Ocean to call for the last detailed build page in depended of the build number.
* instead of *.../blue/organizations/jenkins/Playground_RTM/detail/Playground_RTM/112/pipeline*
* something like that *.../blue/organizations/jenkins/Playground_RTM/detail/Playground_RTM/last/pipeline*

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins - Get last completed build status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238616/jenkins-get-last-completed-build-status)

Comment: I figured out that in Jenkins term I'm looking for permandent link for the last build wihtin the blue ocean system simular than in the old jenkins web interface.

Comment: @SebastianPliefke, what was the url pattern that worked? Judging by https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41088, there is no solution for blue ocean.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a direct dynamic URL in the blue ocean for the last build.

If somebody is looking for providing a quick access link, they could provide link to activity page for a particular branch in blue ocean.

```
https://<host-name>/blue/organizations/jenkins/<job-name>/activity?branch=<branch-name>
```

Or provide the last build page URL for classic Jenkins by using the `lastBuild` keyword.