# I have Job A and B in Jenkins. How can I always execute a file in the most recent build of A in the build steps in job B

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli, jenkins-scriptler, jenkins-build-flow

I have these Jenkins jobs A and B. Job A Builds a bunch of Files for my project. In Job B i wanna execute a command to run a file in the most recent build of job A.
My execution even works fine, but only because I have hard coded the build number and I am picking that from  the files stored by Jenkins in my C:JenkinsData Directory, I would wanna have that called from the Workspace instead
See image for clarification.
[Jenkins build steps illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WV7e.png)

For e.g my last build right now is 70 I want to know how I can be always executing those same files but in the most recent Build

Or if its even way better Can I execute those same file from  Job A since the built files are in the Workspace.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the last build index using this API and "number" property:
/lastBuild/api/json

ie:
http://localhost:8080/job/yourJobName/lastBuild/api/json

This could help:
[Jenkins - Get last completed build status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238616/jenkins-get-last-completed-build-status)

Comment: I can get the build number using the API. Remember Since, My Job B is called to execute immediately after job A completes..  How can I pass that build number in the Build steps of that Job B automatically?

Comment: The idea is to get it from a http request using Invoke-WebRequest command or curl before running your command thanks to the lastBuild API above