# Trigger pipeline A form pipeline B in Jenkins if there is no last successful build of pipeline A

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

There are two Jenkins pipelines A and B. I want to trigger pipeline A from B depending on the values of certain env variables of last successful build of pipeline A (if it exists). How can I achieve this form pipeline B.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Jenkins-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238616/jenkins-get-last-completed-build-status) to collect the last success build in variable
like,

> curl --user {username}:{password} http://{URL}/job/{JOB-NAME}/lastFailedBuild/api/json

then use 'if' condition in first of all in pipeline B.